# Wrong Creation time for article and error on edit of existing article

Tags: joomla-3.x, k2

This may have been discussed but I can't find a fix.

I get the following error when Saving an existing article.
0 DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (-1-11-30 03:00:00) at position 5 (-): Double timezone specification

My article creation dates are wrong.
Created date Monday, 30 November -0001 03:00

This happened after my upgrade to 3.7.3
I am not so much of a code guy but more of a content writer. I would prefer a solution that will not be affected by the next Joomla update.

Thanks in advance for the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to `phpMyAdmin`, and you check the `create_date` for that article, then what do you see? Is it "0000-00-00 00:00"? If it is, then try changing it to a real date and see if that helps solve the problem. If it doesn't, then please comment here.